# "Concerto for Two Violins in A Minor RV 522" from A. Vivaldi, revisited by J.S. Bach

Tags: classical-music, baroque, johann-sebastian-bach

It's the first time I ask a question on musicfans.SE. Please don't be too severe :)

Given the fact that J.S. Bach was very fond of the music of A. Vivaldi, he has revisited many of his pieces.

I am looking for the Bach version of the "Concerto for Two Violins in A Minor RV 522".

I am pretty sure it exists. However, all I could find is "Concerto in D Minor BWV 596" which is the revisitation of  "Concerto grosso Op.3 No. 11".

I am not very knowledgeable in Classical Music. Much of what I know is some pieces of Vivaldi (Violin, Mandoline pieces, and some Operas). I am willing to hear some pieces from J.S. Bach, especially the ones revisiting A. Vivaldi pieces.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is concerned by the answer, I've found it while fetching on a music search engine: the name of the above-mentioned revisitation is "Concerto a-Moll BWV 593" from J.S. Bach.

Comment: You may want to add, that the Bach concerto is set for organ solo.